# multiple daterangepicker on same page with proper validation previous daterange does not select next time

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I am developing dynamic adding date range picker.

We adding every time new input type for selecting date range picker

Can we validate that previously selected date does not select for next date range picker?

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using your daterangepicker's `changeDate` or input `change` event like,

```
// example by using on change event
$('input.datepicker').on('change',function(){
    var inputs=$('input.datepicker').not(this), // get all input which are datepickers
        current_value=this.value, // get date from active input
        flagDate=false; // let the date is not taken previously
    inputs.each(function(){
       if(current_value==this.value){
            flagDate = true; // date is taken in previous fields
            return false;// break the loop
       }
       if(flagDate){
            alert('This date is already taken, please choose another one.');
       }
    });
});
```